# Android - 7 inch emulator opens with black screen

Tags: android, emulation, tablet

I am using AS 2.2.3 with latest Android SDK. I tried to create 7" emulator with all pre-defined 7" skins with SDK 4.3 to 7.1. I also tried to create custom 7" skins. But, none of them works. The emulator starts with black screen forever.

Phone emulators and 9" tablets are fine. 10" emulators are buggy and slow but still working.

Can anyone help me with the 7" emulators, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problems solved. I deleted all ".android*" folders under "/Users/MyUserName/", like ".android", ".android2.0" and etc. Not sure which one solved the problem. When I restarted AS, only ".android" was re-created. I guess that was the one made the problem. I then re-created 7" emulator and it worked fine.

This also improves the performance of 10" emulators.